# How to control the music player using voice commands without internet

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I have created an application which is used to play the songs using voice commands. To play a song, just give command as "play song_name". "pause","resume","stop" commands are also include. I used google voice recognition service to convert voice to text. Everything that i do works fine but i would like to implement that without using internet. If anyone have an idea about it please do help me.

Comment: Try offline toolkits like [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), it works offline

Comment: Yes, CMUSphinx, but it require a lot of space and a lot of power to run on mobile...

Comment: Consider that you cant do this offline. It require too much power (calculating, memory, RAM, etc)

Comment: You probably has some misconception about CMUSphinx. It doesn't require a lot of space (it needs about 4mb) and not so much power (it can run continuously for 1 day on modern device). It's way more efficient than network transmission.